# OkHttp3 Class not found Exception but is present in apk's dex file

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, okhttp, dex

I am building an android library that uses okhttp version 3.10.0 and it works so far. No compiler issues, functioning requests in the test app and everything is fine. As soon as i want to include the built aar file in another app i get a ClassNotFoundException

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.OkHttpClient" on path: DexPathList[...]
```

I already tried every possible combination of any proguard rules i could find on the web (in the library project as well as in the app) and even disabled proguard to be sure it's not some obfuscation or optimization problem.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
    }
}
```

Also i analyzed the built apk in android studio and found exactly the class i need in the correct package of the apk's classes.dex file. So i have absolutely no idea left on what could cause this exception.

gradle versions are 2.1.3 in the lib and 2.2.2 in the app. Let me know if you need more information and thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Including OkHttp as separate dependency to the app project works just fine. Looks like the classes aren't copied correctly. Somehow they exist but can't be used/found (does that make sense?).

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-enable proguard and add this rules to **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

Tell me if getting another `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Already tried that. Yes, i get the exact same error. BUT: i found out that it works if i ad OkHttp as an extra dependency to the app project. Seems like the classes don't get copied by the gradle task but still exist in the dex somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed part of aar library, you can't because AAR doesn't include library, you have to add okhttp to main project

Comment: Is there a way with a gradle version this old to copy the OkHttp classes into the aar file without getting clashes when someone needs another version of OkHttp in their app?

Comment: Is there anyone solve this issue? I want to remove or obfuscate OkHttp3 class in my dex file

Comment: Did you solve this? What are the available workarounds? Is it possible that a lot of dependencies are as such? That if you create an obfuscated aar file, you need to have dependencies that were set to it - to be in the app that uses it?